# SQL convert varchar into Date

Tags: sql, vb.net

A long time ago I created a database, and completely forgot to set the column to `Date` and now looking at the data, I want to extract, it looks like `2006-05-06`.

How would I run a SQL statement to convert it into the correct format (dd/MM/yyyy) 06/05/2006, I'm running with the British format "103".

What I was planning on doing, I've already added a second column (`s_batch_convert2`) to the database, hoping to convert into that and then delete the original column (`s_batch_convert`), renaming the new column to the old one.

```
UPDATE s_service_repairs
SET s_batch_convert2 = TRY_CONVERT(Date, s_batch_convert, 103)
```

Am I along the right lines?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: The correct format *is* YYYY-MM-DD (this is ISO standard and used in most databases).  If you want it output in a different format, then convert it when you output it.  Store the value as a date!

Comment: Fair enough, but looking at the database when i've logged a date for another bit is stored as dd/MM/yyyy, i've changed the .net code to do it correctly, but with the existing 53,929 entries i need to convert which is an pain.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your existing column to a bona fide date.  It seems to have the right format:

```
alter table s_service_repairs alter column s_batch_convert date;
```

Then you can add a computed column for the format you want:

```
alter table s_service_repairs s_batch_convert_mmddyyyy as ( try_convert(varchar(10), s_batch_convert, 103) );
```